# Why the default mint() signatures in OpenZeppelin's ERC1155 wizard use "onlyOwner" modifier?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, modifiers

If you visit OpenZeppelin's ERC1155 wizard (https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc1155) and check the "Mintable" checkbox, two functions will be created in the contract:

```
function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    _mint(account, id, amount, data);
}

function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
    public
    onlyOwner
{
    _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
}
```

Why both of them use `onlyOwner` modifier? Shouldn't minting be available to anyone, not only the owner of the contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erc1155 expose a mint() and mintbatch() functionality for owners.

A public functionality is neither  part of the ERC20, normally you can add your mint method if you want it public:

```
function mintEveyone(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
    public
{
    _mint(account, id, amount, data);
}
```

The ERC1155 includes only an additional method for owners.

Hopt it helps